# which .js files have to be included for datepicker using pickdate.js

Tags: php, jquery-ui, datepicker

After downloading pickdate.js package from http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/ 
I get a very big folder consisting of many files and sub folders, which files among them must be linked in the  tag of my html to use the datepicker?

If I have to link all the .js files, is there any shortcut to link the whole folder with a single line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you'd have instructions bundled in, does the download not include a readme-file? Looking at their [GitHub page](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js); it says this:

> There are three picker files:

- picker.js The core file (required before any other picker)
- picker.date.js The date picker
- picker.time.js The time picker
- To support old browsers, namely IE8, also include the legacy.js file.

> There are two themes:

- default.css The default modal-style theme
- classic.css The classic dropdown-style theme

> Based on the theme, pick the relevant picker styles:

- default.date.css and default.time.css when using the default theme
- classic.date.css and classic.time.css when using the classic theme

You certainly don't need to link up each and every JS file. The above picker files will take care of the rest. Beyond that, there is no shortcut, unless you bundle them up into a single file per JS and CSS.

Comment: .It does not work. I have linked the three .js picker files and the relevant default.css files and i want the datepicker to work in a input field with id "muldate" , so i used the following code in <script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".muldate").pickdate();
  });

Comment: there is no readme.txt file in the folder but there is readme.md ,but how to read this .md file

Comment: Open up the readme.md in any text editor, it's a plain text file. Have you verified that you've *correctly* linked all the files, ie. that you can load in your browser the URLs shown in your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the codepen examples link given on their site. http://codepen.io/collection/vLcih/

Only JS reference included in codepen is -

```
http://http://amsul.github.io/pickadate.js
```